# Google GCS Client Library の GcsFileOptions で java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, google-app-engine, guava

GAE/Java + Slim3 において、

```
new GcsFileOptions.Builder()
.mimeType(mimeType).acl("bucket-owner-full-control")
.build();
```

を実行した際に `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` が発生してしまいます。昨日デプロイしたプロジェクトのみで発生しており、その他の同処理を含んだプロジェクトでは発生しております。

原因ご存じの方いましたら対策ご教授下さい。

以下ログ：

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.createUnstarted()Lcom/google/common/base/Stopwatch;
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:156)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl.createOrReplace(GcsServiceImpl.java:70)
    at com.cresco.apps.report.service.GoogleCloudStorageService.getNewFile(GoogleCloudStorageService.java:56)
    at com.cresco.apps.report.service.GoogleCloudStorageService.doFileItemUpload(GoogleCloudStorageService.java:84)
    at com.cresco.apps.report.controller.maintenance.ImportController.doPost(ImportController.java:229)
    at com.cresco.apps.report.controller.maintenance.ImportController.run(ImportController.java:127)
    at org.slim3.controller.Controller.runBare(Controller.java:111)
    at org.slim3.controller.FrontController.processController(FrontController.java:491)
    at org.slim3.controller.FrontController.doFilter(FrontController.java:277)
    at org.slim3.controller.FrontController.doFilter(FrontController.java:237)
    at org.slim3.controller.FrontController.doFilter(FrontController.java:199)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.slim3.datastore.DatastoreFilter.doFilter(DatastoreFilter.java:55)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.slim3.controller.HotReloadingFilter.doFilter(HotReloadingFilter.java:192)
    at org.slim3.controller.HotReloadingFilter.doFilter(HotReloadingFilter.java:157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:254)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:484)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:438)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:445)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:220)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:309)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:301)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:442)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.createUnstarted()Lcom/google/common/base/Stopwatch;
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:156)
```

トレースを見る限り、 `Stopwatch` クラスは見つかるが、 `createUnstarted()` メソッドが見つからないという状態です。 [API ドキュメント](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html#createUnstarted())では、これは Guava バージョン 15 から追加されたメソッドということですから、クラスパスのどこかに、 Guava < 15 を含む jar が存在しているのではないでしょうか？デプロイ先、または pom.xml や、IDEプロジェクト設定のクラスパスに古いものがないか見なおしてみるといいかもしれません。

（緊急には、 ClassLoader の読込優先度が高い場所に guava => 15 を置くというのがありますが、場当たり的なのでお勧めできません。）